# NSDecimalRound in Swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

Trying to figure out the 'correct' way to round down decimal numbers in Swift and struggling to set up the C calls correctly (or something) as it is returning a weird result. Here's a snippet from Playground:

```
import Foundation

func roundTo2(result: UnsafePointer<Double>, number: UnsafePointer<Double>) {

    var resultCOP = COpaquePointer(result)
    var numberCOP = COpaquePointer(number)

    NSDecimalRound(resultCOP, numberCOP, 2, .RoundDown)

}

var from: Double = 1.54762
var to: Double = 0.0

roundTo2(&to, &from)

println("From: \(from), to: \(to)")
```

Output -> **From: 1.54762, to: 1.54761981964356**

I was hoping for 1.54. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `NSDecimalRound()` actually operates on values of the type `struct NSDecimal`, not on doubles. Support for `NSDecimal` has only been added in Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.3.

Comment: Thank you and to all that replied. It was a bit frustrating (and a learning experience) trying to follow the Apple docs and trying to figure out COpaquePointer and the like. This gives me a few options.

Comment: It seems that COpaquePointer is not for int, double, char but only non-standard. https://tetontech.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/swift-c-libraries-and-mapping-swift-types-to-c-pointer-types/

Comment: I guess then my challenge is figure out how to use 
NSDecimalRound(_:_:_:_:) from Swift which the documentation implies is there. Which would also address the '-ve' rounding issue.

Answer (score 4):

The rounding process should be pretty straightforward without any wrappers. All we should do -- just call the function `NSDecimalRound(_:_:_:_:)`, described there: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1412204-nsdecimalround

```swift
import Cocoa

/// For example let's take any value with multiple decimals like this:
var amount: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(value: 453.585879834)

/// The mutable pointer reserves only "one cell" in memory for the
let uMPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Decimal>.allocate(capacity: 1)

/// Connect the pointer to the value of amount
uMPtr[0] = amount.decimalValue

/// Let's check the connection between variable/pointee and the poiner
Swift.print(uMPtr.pointee) /// result: 453.5858798339999232

/// One more pointer to the pointer
let uPtr = UnsafePointer<Decimal>.init(uMPtr)

/// Standard function call
NSDecimalRound(uMPtr, uPtr, Int(2), NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode.bankers)

/// Check the result
Swift.print(uMPtr.pointee as NSDecimalNumber) /// result: 453.59
```

Comment: Swift feels like an intern project. So many gaps requiring ObjC knowledge...

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
var from: Double = 1.54762
var to: Double = 0.0

let decimalSize = 2.0 //you want to round for 2 digits after decimal point, change to your right value
let k = pow(10.0, decimalSize) //k here is 100

let cent = from*k

/*
get floor (integer) value of this double, 
equal or less than 'cent'.You will get 154. 
For negative value, it will return-155. 
If you want to get -154, you have to use ceil(cent) for cent < 0.
*/
let centRound = floor(cent) 

to = centRound/k
println("From: \(from), to: \(to)")
```

Comment: What about negative values?

Comment: it depends on how to round, floor = get the nearest Int that equal or less than the value, ceil = get the nearest Int that equal or bigger to the value.

Comment: You need sign, abs and floor or ceil functions to calculate the right number. You still will mix integer and float or double numbers. It is better to avoid this. Use equivalent of printf to present the number but store the numbers as double is the best of both worlds. So, my recommendation is don't calculate rounded numbers if you don't really need it in some very specific situation!

Answer (score 0):

As additional info to [HoaParis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1455816/hoaparis) answer, you can make an extensions for Double so you can call it easily again later:

```
extension Double{
    func roundDown(decimals:Int)->Double{
        var from: Double = self
        var to: Double = 0.0

        let decimalSize = 2.0 //you want to round for 2 digits after decimal point, change to your right value
        let k = pow(10.0, Double(decimals)) //k here is 100

        var cent = from*k

        var centRound = floor(cent) //get floor (integer) value of this double.You will get 154.

        to = centRound/k
        return to
    }
}

var from: Double = 1.54762

from.roundDown(2)// 1.54
from.roundDown(3)// 1.547
```

Comment: it should be 1.55 and 1.548

Answer (score 0):

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

// why rounding double (float) numbers is BAD IDEA

let d1 = 0.04499999999999999    // 0.045
let d2 = d1 + 5e-18             // 0.045 (a 'little bit' bigger)
let dd = d2 - d1                // 0.00000000000000000693889390390723
dd == 5e-18                     // false


// this should work by mathematical theory
// and it wokrks ...
// BUT!! the Double DOESN'T means Decimal Number

func round(d: Double, decimalNumbers: UInt) -> Double {
    let p = pow(10.0, Double(decimalNumbers))
    let s = d < 0.0 ? -1.0 : 1.0
    let dabs = p * abs(d) + 0.5
    return s * floor(dabs) / p
}

// this works as expected
let r1 = round(d1, 3)           // 0.045
let r2 = round(d2, 3)           // 0.045
r1 == r2                        // true

// this works only in our heads, not in my computer
// as expected too ... :-)
let r11 = round(d1, 2)          // 0.04
let r21 = round(d2, 2)          // 0.05
r11 == r21                      // false

// look at the difference, it is just about the decimal numbers required
// are you able predict such a result?
```